# Какая тут рекурентная формула?

Tags: c++, математика, рекурсия, формулы

Определить закономерность формирования последовательности, записать рекуррентное соотношение для n-го члена последовательности. Реализовать рекурсивную функцию вычисления n члена последовательности.
Добавил попытку кода, но на формула не хватает познания и разума)

[image: Не могу понять какая тут формула]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Учебные примеры разрешается выкладывать только вместе с вашими попытками в виде кода.

Comment: Вот если бы вместо "1,2" было "1/2", то все укладывалось бы в очень простую схему... А так первые два элемента что-то вписываться не хотят...

Comment: Да, под корнем возрастание степени на 2, над радикалом - в 2.

Comment: Ну, предположим... `a(n) = a(n-1) * pow(2, pow(-0.5, n-1))`, где `a(0) = 1`. Последовательность выглядит как сходящаяся к кубическому корню из четырёх, но это не точно.

Comment: Рекуррентная формула: `a(n) = sqrt(a(n-1) * a(n-2))`, как я понимаю. Ее можно заметить, если прологарифмировать последовательность и получить последовательность 0, 1, 1/2, 3/4, 5/8.